# Google Home Recording Audio

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I know it wasn't available a few years ago, but does anyone know if you can record audio input using Google Home?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

"Hey Google, record my voice."

> Sorry, I can't record anything or take a picture.